# how to load a custom python module in c

Tags: python, c, embed

I am , as of now, simply trying to get [this example](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding) given in the python docs for embedding a python module in C to work.  My problem is I can't figure out where to put the python script.  My ultimate goal is to have a full python package (folder with a `__init__.py` and various modules) to be loadable in C by executing `PyImport_Import(...)`.  But for now, please just let me know where to put the script shown (filename, path, etc) so that the C program given will run.

**EDIT**

I should point out what I've tried.  I have tried putting a `multiply.py` file in the local directory, as well as putting it in a subdirectory called `multiply` in an `__init__.py` file.  In all of these cases, I get `ImportError: No module named multiply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be in the same directory or in `sys.path` as it loads a module by name, this should work:

```
./call multiply multiply 5 6
```

Update: if I add the current directory explicitly to `sys.path` it works:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
```

And this prints:

```
./call multiply multiply 5 6
('Will compute', 5, 'times', 6)
Result of call: 30
```

**Update**: I've asked a relevant question and it seems that if you just add `PySys_SetArgv` instead it works:

```
Py_Initialize();
PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
```

The reason is mentioned here:

> Otherwise (that is, if argc is 0 or argv[0] doesn’t point to an
>   existing file name), an empty string is prepended to sys.path, **which
>   is the same as prepending the current working directory (".")**

And this is the question you can check the answers there too:

[Why does PyImport_Import fail to load a module from the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422764/why-does-pyimport-import-fail-to-load-a-module-from-the-current-directory/13424007#13424007)

Comment: `PyImport_Import(...)` expects a module name.

Comment: @ewok how do you run the program ?

Comment: @mux exactly as told in the docs: `call multiply multiply 3 2`

Comment: @mux got it!  the path was the problem

Comment: @ewok yup, but python should look into the current directory for modules, I think the problem is in `PyImport_Import` I'll check.