# How can I load and execute python script in C++ application

Tags: c++, python, c

I want to extend my application, which is written in C++ using python scripts (extensions). I originally wanted to use TCL for that, just like they do in xchat, for example, but later I decided to use python, because it seems to be quite popular for whatever reasons.

However, I am failing to load and execute even very simple python script. I followed http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

When I give a filename of script that I want to load as argument to `pName`, the error I get from `PyErr_Print` is: ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.

Reading the documentation, I figured I might need to run `PyImport_ExecCodeModule`, however this C function requires 2 arguments, 1 is char * (probably a name of module), other one is compiled python code, which according to docs I can get by calling python function `compile()`. Unfortunately it doesn't say how do I call this python function using C api's in my C++ code. Ideally I would imagine to do something like

```
PyObject *code = PyCompile("print (\"hello :)\"");
```

but I couldn't find any function like PyCompile, neither any other C-api function that would simply allowed me to execute python internal function (like compile) and grab its output as `PyObject`.

So, question is: how can I easily load a python script from a file (something.py) and execute it within my application using the embedded python interpretor?

Comment: Can you show the C++ code you wrote to embed python?

Comment: @SethMMorton the code is pretty similar to what is in example on linked page, in fact I am getting the same error if I just compile the C code on the page, that means: I compile http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding and create the example multiple python script, then calling the "call multiply multiply 1 2" returns the mentioned error: ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.

Comment: * in fact the error is returned when I do call ./multiply multiply 2 4 when I do just call multiply multiply 2 4 I get ImportError: No module named multiply ANYWAY - I want to be able to load the script from a given file

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422764/why-does-pyimport-import-fail-to-load-a-module-from-the-current-directory